# Is it possible not to use Flask decorators?

Tags: python, flask

I don't know why, but I don't like decorators. Can I use

```
def load_user():
    if "user_id" in session:
        g.user = db.session.get(session["user_id"])

app.before_request(load_user)
```

instead of

```
@app.before_request
def load_user():
    if "user_id" in session:
        g.user = db.session.get(session["user_id"])
```

?

Comment: probably yes, you'd need to test it. however, why? this just confuses other developers looking at your code. don't avoid newer/obscure features of a language just because they are newer/obscure, being adaptive to change will make you a better developer

Comment: That *is* using the decorator! To be exactly equivalent, then re-assign the result to the same name: `load_user = app.before_request(load_user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorator returns a new function, which the `@decorator` syntax assigns to the function being defined. Without using that syntax you need to reassign the function name.

```
def load_user():
    if "user_id" in session:
        g.user = db.session.get(session["user_id"])

load_user = app.before_request(load_user)
```

Comment: This is a Flask function, you wouldn't (usually) ever call this function manually, so there's no reason to store the value returned from the decorator function

Comment: I was thinking more generally, but since that's moot here I've removed that part of the answer.